# Setting RestClient SSL version to SSLv3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, rest-client

Is there a way to force SSL version on a single RestClient connection?

I need to set it to 'SSLv3'.

I'm able to do that for ALL connections using:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS[:ssl_version] = 'SSLv3'
```

But that of course is too global.

When trying to pass parameters in the initialization, it doesn't work:

```
RestClient::Resource.new('https://example.com',:ssl_version => "SSLv3")
```

Comment: Technically, you can't use OpenSSL method above to set the encryption for all connections. SSLv3 is hard-coded in RestClient. https://github.com/treeder/rest_client/blob/master/lib/restclient/request.rb#L59 (at least for the gem'd version)

Answer (score 3):

You can use an invocation like this:

```
RestClient::Request.execute(:url => 'https://example.com', :ssl_version => 'SSLv3', :method => 'get')
```

But note that older versions of rest-client would silently discard the :ssl_version option. You can test whether this is happening by using a bogus SSL version:

```
>> RestClient::Request.execute(:url => 'https://example.com', :ssl_version => 'blah', :method => 'get')
ArgumentError: unknown SSL method `blah'.
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/ssl-internal.rb:38:in `ssl_version='
```